# Javascript - Check array for number of occurences of value and return true or false

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a array of objects with the property status, where I want to return false IF

I have (zero slots with "return" or zero "ordered" status or 1 slot with "verification" or 1 "active" status)

```
const slots = [
  {
    status: 'void'
  },
  {
    status: 'closed'
  },
  {
    status: 'ordered'
  },
  {
    status: 'verification'
  },
  {
    status: 'active'
  }
]
```

I don't want to make like

```
x = slots.filter((val) => val.status === 'verification' || val.status === 'active'
 if (x.length > 1) return false

y = slots.filter((val) => val.status === 'return' && val.status === 'ordered')
 if (y.length > 0) return false
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently and in just one "function"?

Comment: *I don't want to make like* - why? *in just one call* - what do you mean by *call*?

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for `false` IF: (zero slots with "return") OR (zero slots with "ordered") OR (1 slot with "verification") OR (1 slot with "active")  ??

Comment: If you're trying to do this with a single `filter()`, I don't see that happening because your conditions require different lengths and `filter()` won't be able to verify both a 0 length and 1 length at the same time. The if/return statement could be condensed into 1 line though.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes.. sorry, i added unecessary (

Comment: Alternatively, return `true` IF: (1 or more slots with "return") AND (1 or more slots with "ordered") AND ((0 or (2 or more)) slots with "verification") AND (0 or (2 or more)) slots with "active") ??

Comment: @RafaelPolonio I was just thinking about this, what if you have the same value more than once, say you have the value `active` twice but no `verification` value, is that still a true or would that need to evaluate to false as well? In other words, do you need to do a group by with count?

Comment: Should the example of *slots* you have given return true or false?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, using `filter` you'll still need to call the `filter` method more than once as your conditions are different, but you could combine it into one line like the following, with a short circuit on the **conditional and** (where left hand side evaluates to false) which in some cases could produce only one call to `filter`:

```js
const slots = [
  {
    status: 'void'
  },
  {
    status: 'closed'
  },
  {
    status: 'ordered'
  },
  {
    status: 'verification'
  },
  {
    status: 'active'
  }
];

function checkslots(slots){
    return slots.filter((val) => val.status === 'verification' || 
        val.status === 'active').length <= 1 &&
        slots.filter((val) => val.status === 'return' && 
        val.status === 'ordered').length <= 0;
}

console.log(checkslots(slots));
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d be inclined to make an object out of slots and test the created properties.  I think the logic is a little clearer like that, since the condition is quite complex.

```js
const slots = [{
    status: 'void'
  },
  {
    status: 'closed'
  },
  {
    status: 'ordered'
  },
  {
    status: 'verification'
  },
  {
    status: 'active'
  }
]

function check(slots) {
  const o = Object.fromEntries(slots.map(s => [s.status, true]))

  if ((o.verification || o.active) && !o.return && !o.ordered) return false;

  return true;
}

console.log(check(slots));
```

Comment: I don't think this reflects the `> 0` and `> 1` checks, though.

Comment: It should, @caTS, but unfortunately I can’t make it a snippet since it doesn’t like my phone.

Comment: Thank you!  Now the logic in the question has changed so let’s see where this settles.

Answer (score 0):

This approach calculates the count of each of the different statuses, and then applies the OR rules to those counts.

```js
const slots = [{status:"void"},{status:"closed"},{status:"ordered"},{status:"verification"},{status:"active"}];
const c = slots.reduce((a,{status:s})=>(a[s]??=0, a[s]++, a),{});
const r = !( !c.return || !c.ordered || c.verification===1 || c.active===1 );
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

For `x` you can use a combination of `Array#filter` with `Array#includes` and for `y` a combination of `Array#every` and `Array#includes` methods as follows:

```js
const 
   slots = [ { status: 'void' }, { status: 'closed' }, { status: 'ordered' }, { status: 'verification' }, { status: 'active' } ],
   
   x = slots
     .filter(
         ({status}) => !['verification','active'].includes(status)
     ).length === 1,
   
   y = slots
     .every(
         ({status}) => !['return', 'ordered'].includes(status)
     );
     
console.log( x, y, x || y );
```